# Payment Method Selected on Woocommerce Cart page should be active on Checkout Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I had added three buttons to the cart page, one for each payment method. Clicking on one of the buttons led to the checkout page where the corresponding payment method used to be pre-selected. It used to work, but somehow has stopped working after updating to the latest Woocommerce version. Any other way of doing this?

Here is the code in `cart.php` template for the buttons:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="submit" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" name="proceed" value="<?php _e( 'Order with Purchase Order', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" name="proceed" value="<?php _e( 'Order with PayPal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" name="proceed" value="<?php _e( 'Order with Credit Card', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
        <?php /*do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' );*/ ?>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart' ); ?>
</form>
```